# Net Core Model Binding Failure after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

having trouble using model data after a POST. I've included the relevant code for the method called after POST, the .cshtml code that does the POSTing, and the ViewModel. Note while I haven't included it here, I have tried using [FromForm]: public string UpdateSpoiler([FromForm] SpoilerAnalysisViewModel temp)

Default routing is in place. When the .cshtml page is first generated, it does have the proper set name defined. After POST, all data is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

View model class:

```
public class SpoilerAnalysisViewModel
    {
        public string SetName = string.Empty;

        // Colors
        public bool White = true;
        public bool Blue = true;
        public bool Black = true;
        public bool Red = true;
        public bool Green = true;
        public bool Colorless = true;

        // CMC range
        public byte minCMC = 0;
        public byte maxCMC = 15;

        // Card types
        public bool Creature = true;
        public bool Instant = true;
        public bool Sorcery = true;
        public bool Enchantment = true;
        public bool Artifact = true;
        public bool Land = true;

        // Rarities
        public bool Limited = true;
        public bool Mythics = true;
        public bool Rares = true;
        public bool Uncommons = true;
        public bool Commons = true;

    }
```

.cshtml file:

```
@model SpoilerAnalysisViewModel;

<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("RefreshSpoiler", "SpoilerAnalysis", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.White) White
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.minCMC) Minimum CMC
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SetName) Current Set
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Method called after POST

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string RefreshSpoiler(SpoilerAnalysisViewModel temp)
    {
        if (temp == null) return "model is null";
        return "set: " + temp.SetName;
    }
```

Comment: Change your fields to properties public bool Creature {get;set;} = true;

Answer (score 0):

Your model just `Set` the values it doesn't have a `Get`.
so if you want set the values you need to set it in another way like this :

Assuming your model is

```
public class SpoilerAnalysisViewModel
{
 public public bool White{ get; set; }
 ....
}
```

then you can set the values :

```
 SpoilerAnalysisViewModel model = new SpoilerAnalysisViewModel()
 {
   White= True;
   ....
 };
```